# query returns no record using CONTAINS() VSS asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sqlcommand

Im having trouble on returning records using contains(transact-SQL).

this query has results on SQL server query window using static value

```
select * from archive_master where docgroupID=46 and( CONTAINS((docno,docname,accountno,accountName,tags,docyear,docmonth),'"1"')
   OR CONTAINS((docno,docname,accountno,accountName,tags,docyear,docmonth),'"*1"')
   OR CONTAINS((docno,docname,accountno,accountName,tags,docyear,docmonth),'"1*"')
   OR CONTAINS((docno,docname,accountno,accountName,tags,docyear,docmonth),'"*1*"')
   )
```

however if i put the query to sqlcommand and replacing the static value with parameters, it returns no record

heres my code:

```
string oconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ARCHDB"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection empCon = new SqlConnection(oconn))
    {


        if (txtsearch.Text == "")
        {
            query = "select * from archive_master where docgroupID=@docgroupID";
         }
        else
        {
           query = @"select * from archive_master where docgroupID=@docgroupID and (CONTAINS((docno, docname, accountno, accountName, tags, docyear, docmonth), '""@qry""') OR CONTAINS((docno, docname, accountno, accountName, tags, docyear, docmonth), ""*@qry"")  OR CONTAINS((docno, docname, accountno, accountName, tags, docyear, docmonth), ""@qry*"")  OR CONTAINS((docno, docname, accountno, accountName, tags, docyear, docmonth), ""*@qry*""))";
        }


        using (SqlCommand emp_Cmd = new SqlCommand(query, empCon))
        {

            if (txtsearch.Text == "")
            {
                SqlParameter pdocgroupID = emp_Cmd.Parameters.Add("@docgroupID", SqlDbType.BigInt);
                pdocgroupID.Value = Request.QueryString["docgroupID"];
            }
            else
            {
                SqlParameter pdocgroupID = emp_Cmd.Parameters.Add("@docgroupID",SqlDbType.BigInt);
                SqlParameter pqry = emp_Cmd.Parameters.Add("@qry", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                pdocgroupID.Value = Request.QueryString["docgroupID"];
                pqry.Value = txtsearch.Text;
            }



            emp_Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            empCon.Open();

            SqlDataAdapter adpData = new SqlDataAdapter(emp_Cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adpData.Fill(dt);


            GridDocgroup.DataSource = dt;
            GridDocgroup.DataBind();
            empCon.Close();




        }
    }
```

is my approach on my query string correct? where @qry and @docgroupID are parameters

```
  query = @"select * from archive_master where docgroupID=@docgroupID and (CONTAINS((docno, docname, accountno, accountName, tags, docyear, docmonth), '""@qry""') OR CONTAINS((docno, docname, accountno, accountName, tags, docyear, docmonth), ""*@qry"")  OR CONTAINS((docno, docname, accountno, accountName, tags, docyear, docmonth), ""@qry*"")  OR CONTAINS((docno, docname, accountno, accountName, tags, docyear, docmonth), ""*@qry*""))";
```

Comment: can you please try below changed query and execute code again  "select * from archive_master where docgroupID=@docgroupID and (CONTAINS((docno, docname, accountno, accountName, tags, docyear, docmonth), '"@qry"') OR CONTAINS((docno, docname, accountno, accountName, tags, docyear, docmonth), '"*@qry"')  OR CONTAINS((docno, docname, accountno, accountName, tags, docyear, docmonth), '"@qry*"')  OR CONTAINS((docno, docname, accountno, accountName, tags, docyear, docmonth), '"*@qry*"'))"

Comment: hi Kevin, This query will return a value if the word is in exact phrase, im trying to search part of the phrase (prefix and suffix) using the * wildcard

Comment: Yes that I know you have created fulltext index on database

Comment: In your query you need to put single quote (') before ""@qry"" as if you see in the sql query that you have executed in sequal server

Comment: query = @"select * from archive_master where docgroupID=@docgroupID and (CONTAINS((docno, docname, accountno, accountName, tags, docyear, docmonth), '""@qry""') OR CONTAINS((docno, docname, accountno, accountName, tags, docyear, docmonth), '""*@qry""')  OR CONTAINS((docno, docname, accountno, accountName, tags, docyear, docmonth), '""@qry*""')  OR CONTAINS((docno, docname, accountno, accountName, tags, docyear, docmonth), '""*@qry*""'))";
         tried this query still shows no record. i think the asterisk is not posting here in comment as it is being treated as text format.

Answer (score 0):

as a work around i revised the query and pass the wildcard on parameters value

```
  query = @"select * from archive_master where docgroupID=@docgroupID and (CONTAINS((docno, docname, accountno, accountName, tags, docyear, docmonth), @qry1) OR CONTAINS((docno, docname, accountno, accountName, tags, docyear, docmonth), @qry2)  OR CONTAINS((docno, docname, accountno, accountName, tags, docyear, docmonth), @qry3)  OR CONTAINS((docno, docname, accountno, accountName, tags, docyear, docmonth), @qry4))";

SqlParameter pdocgroupID = emp_Cmd.Parameters.Add("@docgroupID",SqlDbType.BigInt);
                    SqlParameter pqry1= emp_Cmd.Parameters.Add("@qry1", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                    SqlParameter pqry2 = emp_Cmd.Parameters.Add("@qry2", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                    SqlParameter pqry3 = emp_Cmd.Parameters.Add("@qry3", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                    SqlParameter pqry4 = emp_Cmd.Parameters.Add("@qry4", SqlDbType.NVarChar);

                    pdocgroupID.Value = Request.QueryString["docgroupID"];
                    pqry1.Value =txtsearch.Text.Trim();
                    pqry2.Value = '"'+ txtsearch.Text.Trim()+"*"+'"';
                    pqry3.Value = '"'+"*" + txtsearch.Text.Trim() + "*"+'"';
                    pqry4.Value = '"'+"*" + txtsearch.Text.Trim()+'"';
```